# how to make checkinstall do install symlinks?

Tags: checkinstall, deb

I have a script that installs normal files and some symlinks to these files on `/usr/bin`, so I use `checkinstall` to create a `.deb` package.

The point is, checkinstall is ignoring the symlinks I create. It makes copies of the real files over the symlinks.

I read thru the options and the info pages and found nothing speaking about symlinks.

Comment: I am quite sure we have to create some kind of post install script to let such symlinks be created, but it would defeat the practicality of checkintall

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue installing an application and solved it by removing the old package and running checkinstall again afterwards. I did not reconfigure or recompile it.